# Turning a 3D graphics object into a region

Tags: graphics3d, regions

I have a somewhat complex 3D shape composed of several polygons:

---

[image: Sofa75]

---

Executing `DiscretizeGraphics[gsofa]` (where `gsofa` is the graphics object)
produces this:

---

[image: SofaDisc]

---

I wanted to convert the graphics object to a region so that I could use derived region functions, but it is clear the discretized region does not correspond to the shape.
Must I partition the U-shaped faces into convex faces?

*Answered* by @JackLaVigne:

---

[image: SofaRegion]

---

Cf. the [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/246914/6094) where this arose.

Comment: Is the "complex shape" a `GraphicsComplex[]` object (easy), or a bunch of `Polygon[]`s (a bit harder)?

Comment: @J.M.: A bunch of polygons. But I guess it wouldn't be too hard to convert to a `GraphicsComplex` if that would help.

Comment: Now that I think about it: a generalized cylinder like your example can be easily generated as a (`Boundary`)`MeshRegion[]` *ab initio*, long as you have coordinates for the top and bottom; a more complicated object like the Stanford bunny would be of course much harder.

Comment: @J.M. I have all vertex coordinates. I will explore `MeshRegion` (with which I was not familiar). Thanks!

Comment: can you do something like this instead? `RegionUnion[
  RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 1/2]],
  RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{-2, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}], 
   Cylinder[{{-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 1]], 
  RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1}], 
   Cylinder[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, 1]]] // DiscretizeRegion`

Comment: Can you post the actual *Mathematica* code of the graphics or is that not possible?

Comment: @RunnyKine: The code is a bit of a mess and would need some curating before posting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how helpful this is because I am going by the figure you have for your shape.

That looks to me like two cylinders pointing in the y direction with a cuboid chopping off the top quarter and a second cuboid chopping off the bottom half. Below is a figure of the two cylinders.

```
Graphics3D[
 {
  {
   Opacity[0.5],
   Cylinder[{{0, 1/4, 0}, {0, 3/4, 0}}, 1],
   Opacity[1],
   Cylinder[{{0, 1/4, 0}, {0, 3/4, 0}}, 1/4]
   }
  },
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now create the cylinders as a region difference and remove the top quarter

```
cylinders = RegionDifference[
  Cylinder[{{0, 1/4, 0}, {0, 3/4, 0}}, 1],
  Cylinder[{{0, 1/4, 0}, {0, 3/4, 0}}, 1/4]
  ]

cylindersMinusTop = RegionDifference[cylinders, Cuboid[{-1, -1, 1/2}, {1, 1, 1}]]

RegionPlot3D[
 cylindersMinusTop,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.5]],
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next remove the bottom half

```
cylindersMinus = RegionDifference[cylindersMinusTop, Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 0}]]

RegionPlot3D[
 cylindersMinus,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.5]],
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 ImageSize -> 350,
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can measure this region

```
RegionMeasure[cylindersMinus]

(* 1/192 (24 Sqrt[3] + 13 π) *)
```

It appears to discretize fine

```
DiscretizeRegion[cylindersMinus]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice, Jack! Let me think about this...